# Python - why is this an infinite loop?

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I have the following code:

```
sum_of_primes = 0
n = 2
while n < 10:
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            n += 1
            break
        else:
            sum_of_primes += i
            n += 1
print(sum_of_primes)
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is an infinite loop.

Below is my modified code which works, but i still don't understand why the original code is creating an infinite loop:

```
counter = 0
primes = 0
number = 2

while counter < 10:

    for x in range(2, number):
        if number % x == 0:
            number += 1
            counter+=1
            break
    else:

        primes +=number
        counter = number
        number += 1

print(primes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that `for i in range(2,n):` and at start point `n=2`. So your range will be `range(2,2)` so it will return empty list so this for loop never executes and your program will be gone in an infinite loop.

And in second code you are using `for...else`

```
for x in range(2, number):
    if number % x == 0:
        number += 1
        counter+=1
        break
else:
    primes +=number
    counter = number
    number += 1
```

Here, the meaning of `for...else` is if for loop will be not executed a single time then the `else` part of for loop will be executed. And in `else` part you are increase the `counter` and `number`.

so, first time `number = 2` and for loop become `for x in range(2, number):` mean for loop will be not executed so, as per I discussed above if for loop is not exceute single time `else` part will be execute

So, in `else` part number will be increased by 1, then in next iteration your for loop become `for x in range(2,3)` so, at that time for loop will be executed successfully...

For `for...else` [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: @abramo I updated my answer for your query, please check it and let me know if you are not understand it.

Comment: Yes Great, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You inner loop is never executed since `range(2, 2)` is empty. Since the inner loop updates `n`, `n` is never changed, so the outer loop will never terminate.

```
n = 2
while n < 10:
    for i in range(2,n):  # list(range(2,2)) == [] ...
        # ... so this loop never executes
        # and n is never updated
    # so this loop runs forever
```

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you, but the second code works where I am supposed to have the same problem of an empty range.

Answer (score 1):

Initially `n` is `2`. The `for` loop is therefore `for i in range(2,2)` which is an empty range so the loop never executes. That means you never get into the code that might increment `n`.

```
sum_of_primes = 0
n = 2
while n < 10:      # n == 2
    for i in range(2,n):   # loop repeats zero times
        if n%i == 0:
            n += 1
            break
        else:
            sum_of_primes += i
            n += 1
    # n == 2 still the case down here.
print(sum_of_primes)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now, but I am still puzzled by the fact that the second code works where I am supposed to have the same problem of an empty range.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(2,n):
```

it means range is (2,2) the loop never started since it's starting and ending is the same that is 2-2.